# how to get the [ scheduledDate ] of pending notification (flutter local notification)

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm using schedule notification, schedule function takes:

- id
- title
- body
- scheduledDate

I can access `id`, `title` and `body`, but **not** `scheduledDate`.
How can I get the `scheduledDate` of pending notification?

This is the code (using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package):

```dart
FutureBuilder(
        future: flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests(),
        builder: (context,ss){
          if(ss.hasError){
            print('Error');
          }
          if(ss.hasData){
            List<PendingNotificationRequest> appointments = ss.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: appointments.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,position){
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('id: ${appointments[position].id}'),
                        Text('title: ${appointments[position].title}'),
                        Text('body: ${appointments[position].body}'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }else{
            return SpinKitRipple(color: Colors.blue[800],);
          }
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your date in **payload** as String parameter when you schedule notification 
then when you fetch Pending notifications ,get the payload then 
convert it to DateTime

This is a solution for me